# Prevent from mutation in original data using Object assign and map problem

Tags: javascript

I have an array with objects:
`data = [{id:"a", position:{x:10,y:10}, parent:'3a'},{id:"b", position:{x:100,y:100}}]`
I am using map method to create new array in which I want to have new prop position but based on exsisting without mutating original value from data array. I know I have to use object assign to prevent from mutating but I can not figure out how to set position basing and not changing original one:

```
          if (e.parent) {
            const newObject = Object.assign({}, e, {
              position: {
                x: (e.position.x -= bbX / 2 - parent.x),
                y: (e.position.y -= bbY / 2 - parent.y)
              }
            });
            return newObject;
          }
          return e;
        });
```

I tried with this one and similar but I still see mutation in original data array when it comes to position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by following lines:

```
x: (e.position.x -= bbX / 2 - parent.x),
y: (e.position.y -= bbY / 2 - parent.y)
```

When you use subtraction assignment operator `-=`, you also assign the result to the left variable which is the orignal data, just subtraction operator `-` would be fine:

```js
const data = [{id:"a", position:{x:10,y:10}, parent:'3a'},{id:"b", position:{x:100,y:100}}];

const newData = data.reduce((arr, cur) => {
      let e = Object.assign({}, cur, {position: {x: (cur.position.x - 5),y: (cur.position.y - 5)}});
      arr.push(e);
      return arr;
},[]);

console.log("original data:" + JSON.stringify(data));

console.log("new data:" + JSON.stringify(newData));
```